# In Julia, why is @printf a macro instead of a function?

Tags: julia

In Julia, the syntax to print a formatted string is as follows:

```
@printf("Hello %d\n", 5)
```

Why is `@printf` a macro instead of a function? Is it so that it can accept a varying number of arguments?

Answer (score 130, accepted):

Taking a variable number of arguments is not a problem for normal Julia functions [[1](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/functions/#Varargs-Functions)]. `@printf` is a macro so that it can parse and interpret the format string at compile time and generate custom code for that specific format string. People may not realize that C's `printf` function re-parses and re-interprets the format string *each time you call `printf`*. The fact that it's as fast as it is represents a minor miracle of insane pointer programming. Seriously, just look at your nearest libc's `printf` implementation. It's completely nuts.

Julia uses a different approach: `@printf` is a macro which translates format strings into efficient code specific to that format specification. If you think about it, a printf-style format string is really just a way to express a function that takes a fixed number and type of arguments and prints them in a particular way. Note that I said that the *format string* is a function, not printf itself, which is conceptually a function generator, turning formats into formatters. The fact that this is all crammed into a run-time function in C is a bit of a mismatch due to that being the only reasonable option in C. In fact, because of this, until very recently, it was rather easy to shoot yourself in the foot by passing the wrong number or type of arguments to C's printf. This is only better now because compilers have been special-cased to understand the semantics of printf formats.

In theory, Julia's `@printf` can be made faster than C since it generate's custom code, but in practice, I had a hard enough time matching C, let alone beating it. But I think that's due to the current design of our I/O system and how I'm using it, not an inherent limitation. The I/O stuff is due for an overhaul though, and when that happens, we might actually be able to beat C at formatted printing by leveraging the fact that `@printf` is a macro.

Comment: @lucacerone do `x = @sprintf "My lucky number is %d" 42`.

Comment: Generating custom code for every printf call is likely to cause a lot of code bloat.

Comment: Interesting update from @StefanKarpinski [here](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/11941#issuecomment-129966921)

Comment: It seems that a disadvantage of this approach is that the format string cannot contain variables. See http://julia-programming-language.2336112.n4.nabble.com/string-BigFloat-disable-scientific-notation-td21455.html

Comment: For completeness, @user44400's page has a variable that controls the number of digits: `value = big(pi); N = 100; @sprintf("%.$Nf", value)`. This fails in Julia 0.6.3 with `ERROR: ArgumentError: @sprintf: format must be a plain static string (no interpolation or prefix)`.

Comment: The fact that you can't use a variable as the format string is not just a disadvantage, it is a significant limitation. The compiler should do this static optimization if the string is static, and leave it as a runtime-parsed printf function otherwise. Using a variable format is a fairly common use case I think.

Comment: at least there is `julia> x = 1.15; round(x, digits=1)` --> `1.2`

Answer (score 7):

It is for performance. The `printf` macro takes a constant format string (eg. `"Hello %d\n"`) and generates optimized code for that string.