# Julia: How to give multiple workers access to functions that are 'include(...)' into a module?

Tags: module, parallel-processing, include, julia

I have the following test module (MyMod.jl) to store some functions in Julia. Some of the core functions are written in serial. Other functions call the core functions in parallel.

```
module MyMod

export Dummy,distribute_data,recombine_data,regular_test,parallel_test

function Dummy(icol,model,data,A,B)
    nz,nx,nh = size(model)  # = size(A) = size(B)
    for ih = 1:nh
        for ix = 1:nx
            for iz = 1:nz
                data[iz,icol] += A[iz,ix,ih]*B[iz,ix,ih]*model[iz,ix,ih]
            end  
        end
    end
end

function distribute_data(X, obj_name_on_worker::Symbol;mod=Main)
    dim = length(size(X))
    size_per_worker = floor(Int,size(X,1) / nworkers())
    StartIdx = 1
    EndIdx = size_per_worker
    for (idx, pid) in enumerate(workers())
        if idx == nworkers()
            EndIdx = size(X,1)
        end
        println(StartIdx:EndIdx)
        if dim == 3
            @spawnat(pid, eval(mod, Expr(:(=), obj_name_on_worker, X[StartIdx:EndIdx,:,:])))
        elseif dim == 2
            @spawnat(pid, eval(mod, Expr(:(=), obj_name_on_worker, X[StartIdx:EndIdx,:])))
        end
        StartIdx = EndIdx + 1
        EndIdx = EndIdx + size_per_worker - 1
    end
end

function recombine_data(Data::Symbol;mod=Main)
    Results = cell(nworkers())
    for (idx, pid) in enumerate(workers())
        Results[idx] = fetch(@spawnat(pid, getfield(mod, Data)))
    end
    return vcat(Results...)
end

function regular_test(model,data,A,B)
    ncol=size(data,2)
    map((arg)->Dummy(arg,model,data,A,B),[icol for icol = 1:ncol])
end

function parallel_test(model,data,A,B)
    distribute_data(model, :model)
    distribute_data(A, :A)
    distribute_data(B, :B)
    distribute_data(data, :data)
    @everywhere ncol=size(data,2)
    @everywhere begin
        if myid() != 1
            map((arg)->Dummy(arg,model,data,A,B),[icol for icol = 1:ncol])
        end
    end
    P_Data = recombine_data(:data)
    return P_Data
end

end
```

This module works as expected. When I open a Julia session and run the following commands I find that the `regular_test` gives the same result as the `parallel_test` without any errors.

```
addprocs(3)

@everywhere using MyMod

nx = 250;
nz = 350;
nh = 150;
ncol = 125;

model = rand(nz,nx,nh);
data = SharedArray(Float64,nz,ncol);
A = rand(nz,nx,nh);
B = rand(nz,nx,nh);

@time P_Data = parallel_test(model,data,A,B);
@time regular_test(model,data,A,B); 

P_Data == data
```

For larger/complicated functions it becomes quite messy to store modules in this way. Previously I have cleaned things up by storing each function as a separate file and then using `include(..)` to bring them into the module.  The following module is my attempt to do just that:

```
module MyMod_2

export Dummy,distribute_data,recombine_data,regular_test,parallel_test

@everywhere include("Dummy.jl")
@everywhere include("distribute_data.jl")
@everywhere include("recombine_data.jl")
@everywhere include("regular_test.jl")
@everywhere include("parallel_test.jl")

end
```

where each of the functions are stored as a separate file in the same directory as `MyMod2`. However when I open a Julia session and try to run the same set of commands as before I get the following lengthy error when executing `@everywhere using MyMod_2`

```
WARNING: Module MyMod_2 not defined on process 4
fatal error on WARNING: Module MyMod_2 not defined on process 3
4: fatal error on WARNING: Module MyMod_2 not defined on process 2
3: fatal error on 2: ERROR: UndefVarError: MyMod_2 not defined
 in deserialize at serialize.jl:504
 in handle_deserialize at serialize.jl:465
 in deserialize at serialize.jl:560
 in handle_deserialize at serialize.jl:465
 in deserialize at serialize.jl:538
 in handle_deserialize at serialize.jl:465
 in deserialize at serialize.jl:696
 in deserialize_datatype at serialize.jl:651
 in handle_deserialize at serialize.jl:465
 in message_handler_loop at multi.jl:862
 in process_tcp_streams at multi.jl:851
 in anonymous at task.jl:63
ERROR: UndefVarError: MyMod_2 not defined
 in deserialize at serialize.jl:504
 in handle_deserialize at serialize.jl:465
 in deserialize at serialize.jl:560
 in handle_deserialize at serialize.jl:465
 in deserialize at serialize.jl:538
 in handle_deserialize at serialize.jl:465
 in deserialize at serialize.jl:696
 in deserialize_datatype at serialize.jl:651
 in handle_deserialize at serialize.jl:465
 in message_handler_loop at multi.jl:862
 in process_tcp_streams at multi.jl:851
 in anonymous at task.jl:63
ERROR: UndefVarError: MyMod_2 not defined
 in deserialize at serialize.jl:504
 in handle_deserialize at serialize.jl:465
 in deserialize at serialize.jl:560
 in handle_deserialize at serialize.jl:465
 in deserialize at serialize.jl:538
 in handle_deserialize at serialize.jl:465
 in deserialize at serialize.jl:696
 in deserialize_datatype at serialize.jl:651
 in handle_deserialize at serialize.jl:465
 in message_handler_loop at multi.jl:862
 in process_tcp_streams at multi.jl:851
 in anonymous at task.jl:63
Worker 2 terminated.
ERROR: ProcessExitedException()
 in yieldto at ./task.jl:71
 in wait at ./task.jl:371
 in wait at ./task.jl:286
 in wait at ./channels.jl:63
 in take! at ./channels.jl:53
 in take! at ./multi.jl:803
 in remotecall_fetch at multi.jl:729
 in remotecall_fetch at multi.jl:734
 in anonymous at multi.jl:1380

...and 3 other exceptions.

 in sync_end at ./task.jl:413
 in anonymous at multi.jl:1389
Worker 3 terminated.ERROR (unhandled task failure): EOFError: read end of file


julia> Worker 4 terminated.ERROR (unhandled task failure): EOFError: read end of file
julia> 
fatal error on ERROR (unhandled task failure): EOFError: read end of file
1: ERROR: attempt to send to unknown socket
fatal error on 1: ERROR: attempt to send to unknown socket
```

Is there something I can change to in `MyMod_2` to fix this error and get it to load into the Julia session correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Small tweak - in your module, omit the `@everywhere` macro.  Just using the single `@everywhere` when loading your module should do the trick.  Otherwise, you get into a strange recursive type situation where the workers are all executing the code in your module (from the `@everywhere using MyMod_2`, and then each of those workers is *also* calling `@everywhere include()`)