# What is the proper way to repeat a format string in Julia?

Tags: printf, julia

I have an array of floats `x` and would like to print the last row to screen as integers. The following code does not work and yields `ArgumentError: @printf: first or second argument must be a format string`. How can I print with a variable format string?

```
using Printf
@printf("%i "^length(x[end,:]), x[end,:]...)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `@eval` to compile a simple print statement every time is really a bad approach.  There's no functionality for dynamic format strings etc. because Julia has a wide range of [other](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/strings/) [nice](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/io-network/#Text-I/O-1) tools to achieve the same things:

```
julia> join(stdout, (round(Int, y) for y in x[end, :]), " ")
1 0 1
```

And printing an array is really not what `printf` is made for (not even in C).

That is not to say that a `printf` function taking a runtime format string wouldn't be a nice thing, but see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19784718/1346276) for the reasoning behind making it a macro.  I've never missed `printf`, but in case you really do, there's [Formatting.jl](https://github.com/JuliaIO/Formatting.jl), which provides all functinality you can imagine.

Comment: Could you include a list of other tools available for printing in Julia?

Comment: I ended up implementing the equivalent `join(stdout, round.(Int, x[end,:]), " ")`. Formatting.jl seems helpful if a bit overwhelming.

Comment: It's more a generally rich infrastructure of helper functions, like in Python. And that strings are handled more easily as data structure.

Answer (score 0):

Our "constants" are still run-time values – they are write-once rather than compile-time constants like in C.

As a hack until julia gets real support for runtime format strings, this works:

```
using Printf
const fmt = "%i "^length(x[end,:])
@eval @printf($fmt, x[end,:]...)
```

Comment: try it now please

Comment: That works. This works too `@eval @printf($("%i "^length(x[end,:])), x[end,:]...)`. I don't understand why I need the `$` though since `fmt` is already a string.

Comment: The catch here is we are tricking the Julia compiler to evaluate the format string at compile-time, rather than runtime.

Comment: This answer is technically correct, but not a good recommendation. `@eval` should not just be randomly used to circumevent appearent "restrictions" of macros. You already wrote "hacky", but I still will downvote, until you add an explanation what the hack really does and what the consequences are.